# How to read ASCII data from a serial port into a file in Python

Tags: python

I need to read ASCII data including LF and CR from an external device using the serial port of the PC and write it to a file using Python.

I just started learning Python but I was able to open up a port but now I'm having trouble with the actual reading part because I'm not sure how to specify when data is finished and so the file can be written, can someone please help with some code examples?

The settings for the port are:

```
Serial = 'COM3', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1
```

Comment: "I'm not sure how to specify when data is finished"?  That's not a Python thing.  That's a question you have to ask of your "external device".  How do you know the device is done?  If someone printed out the stream of bytes, how would you know that it ended properly or had the wire yanked out?

Comment: I agree with S.Lott; do you have a spec which tells you what to expect in the data? Maybe there are some clues in there.

Comment: You should probably just register your account here; this will prevent the problem of creating duplicate accounts every time you visit and post a reply. Using the same account will also make comments work properly. I merged your duplicate account.

Answer (score 0):

Head on over to the [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) site and start hacking!.  Here are [examples](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html) to get you going.

In regards to your question, try the `readline()` method.  You may add the CRLF to the end of the string to write if need be.  You can write to the file after each line retrieved.

When the device is finished and the file needs to be closed will be up to your device.  Consult its documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately all I was told was that there's a device that sends ASCII data and they want me to read it from the serial port, the way to circumvent that would be to let the port timeout when the device no longs send data, I'm testing it with com0com since I don't have a serial port on this computer, but even when I set the port to timeout to 3 seconds it doesn't work, the code sits there and reads the port forever, that's the part I need help with, thanks.